# Add images in ListView in Fragment - Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

In my app i am using Navigation Drawer with ListView in Fragment. And i successfully implemented the list view inside Fragment. but now i want to do add image in this list.How to do it. Need some example

This is my Vegall.java file

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Vegall extends Fragment {
    private ListView lv;
    private static String[] vegalllist = {"Vegetables1", "Vegetables2"};

    public static Vegall newInstance()
    {
        Vegall vegall =new Vegall();
        return vegall;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.vegall, null);

        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vegall_lv);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vegalllist));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), vegcat[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectItem(i);

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    private void selectItem(int i){
        Fragment newFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                newFragment = new Vegetables1();
                transaction.replace(R.id.containerID, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;

            case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Vegetables2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Home";
    }

}
```

This is my Vegall.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/vegall_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make customized adapter like BaseAdapter  instead of arrayadapter  and add the images in the drawable folder.
Have a look into the BaseAdapter tutorial 
 http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Answer (score 0):

insert image in the drawable folder and then link it to the xml file use the `<imageview>`